# Is there a simple way to use multiply accumulate in c++?

Tags: c++, fma

I've gotten great performance benefit from using the mad function in the c++AMP library. I was wondering if there is a similar function for regular c++ 11? All I found googling was stuff on AVX intrinsics but I'd rather avoid them due to them not being universally supported.

Also, they seem to be all made for processing 4+ mad operations at the same time and I'm not sure that constructing an environment for that to happen while actually just using 1 of them is even efficient.

Comment: Do you mean something like [inner_product](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product)?

Comment: It depends on your CPU and your compiler, but if your CPU supports FMA (e.g. Haswell) and your compiler is half-way decent then you may already be getting fused multiply-accumulate.

Comment: What do you expect? A _portable_ way? Don't you see it's heavily architecture-dependent?

Comment: @user4419802 according to the answer, yes :p

Comment: @user81993 Well, it's not guaranteed to perform better than just `(x*y+z)`, but usually it should. OK then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C and C++ there is the fma family of math functions:

- C: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fma
- C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fma

As they are part of the standard library they should be portable enough.